# (RESPONSIVE) Change width unit from px to % in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

So I have a content slider on the page here: http://helpmyedu.com/asdtest-2, I'd like to make it responsive (100% width)..
[image]

I have successfully made it responsive by changing the following code in the developer tools:

[image]

However, I can only change the first 100% in the style sheet, the bottom two are control by this piece of javascritp:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.noConflict();

            jQuery('#services-example-1').services(
                {
                    width:1144,
                    height:300,
                    slideAmount:6,
                    slideSpacing:30,
                    touchenabled:"on",
                    mouseWheel:"on",
                    hoverAlpha:"off",
                    slideshow:6000,
                    hovereffect:"on",
                    callBack:function() { }

                });


    });
    </script>
```

How can I make the "width: 1144" into %?

Or howelse can I make this slider responsive?
Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply change one spot and make this slider responsive. You can of course change the value in your js, but you still get the full width slider, because all child elements are still in their original sizes.

What you can do, is to override each element in your css (classes like .imgholder .thumb etc.) so that it will respond to page size, plus, you have to adjust your width in js to a value based on page width, like this:

```
var sliderwidth = 
                    Math.round(parseInt(jQuery('#services-example-1').css('width'))-(50)); //Leave some margin for padding and scroll bar
                    jQuery('#services-example-1').services(
                        {
                            width:sliderwidth,
                            height:300,
                            slideAmount:6,
                            slideSpacing:30,
                            touchenabled:"on",
                            mouseWheel:"on",
                            hoverAlpha:"off",
                            slideshow:6000,
                            hovereffect:"off"
                        });
```

This would solve your problem I hope, I didn't change the height though as you still need that height to contain your images.

Two more thing I noticed:
1. This jquery slider plugin is a bit buggy, especially when you do a page resize, freeze your browser a while and the slider can go missing
2. You have sooooo many css and js in your page, are they all really necessary? Slow down your site mate.

Comment: What do you mean by "override each element"?

Comment: properties for each image/description/button within that slider is defined by the slider js, so you have to do some css hacks to override that in-line style, like .imgholder[style] {width: 20% !important;}, this will override whatever the js creates